# Why don't Python 3.7 dataclasses support < > <= and >=, or do they?

Tags: python, transcrypt, python-3.7, python-dataclasses

For version 3.7.1 of the [Transcrypt Python to JavaScript compiler](http://www.transcrypt.org) I am currently using the new `@dataclass` decorator. I had expected that `==, !=, <, >, >=, <=` would be supported, as per [the PEP's abstract](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/), but it doesn't seem to be the case:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class C:
    x: int = 10
```

Some comparisons are not working:

```
>>> c1 = C(1)
>>> c2 = C(2)
>>> c1 == c2  # ok
False
>>> c1 < c2  # crash
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'C' and 'C'
```

Why are the comparison operators not supported, except for `==` and `!=`? Or did I overlook something?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

They do, just not by default. Per [PEP-557](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/):

> The parameters to `dataclass` are:
>
> ...
>
> - `order`: If true (the default is False), `__lt__`, `__le__`, `__gt__`, and `__ge__` methods will be generated. These compare the
>     class as if it were a tuple of its fields, in order. Both instances in
>     the comparison must be of the identical type. If `order` is true and
>     `eq` is false, a `ValueError` is raised.

So you want `@dataclass(order=True)`.